# How to implement widgets error output with data validation?

Tags: widgets

tell me how to update the widget and check the fields, to implement the output error in the case of incorrectly filled data.

It may have built the functional?

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Sets up the widgets name etc
 */
public function __construct() {
    $widget_ops = array( 
        'classname' => 'my_widget',
        'description' => 'My Widget is awesome',
    );
    parent::__construct( 'my_widget', 'My Widget', $widget_ops );
}

/**
 * Outputs the content of the widget
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @param array $instance
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];        
    echo $instance['title'];
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}

/**
 * Outputs the options form on admin
 *
 * @param array $instance The widget options
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    </p>
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Processing widget options on save
 *
 * @param array $new_instance The new options
 * @param array $old_instance The previous options
 */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {


    // !!!!!!!
    if(empty($new_instance['title'])){
    // !!!!!
    // How to make it clear to the user that he incorrectly filled field?
    // !!!!!
return 'Error!';    
    }}}
```

question function "update($new_instance, $old_instance)"

Comment: Can you elaborate more? we need a bit of context, usually you can do that in the definition of your widget

Comment: I added a simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Sets up the widgets name etc
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname' => 'my_widget',
            'description' => 'My Widget is awesome',
        );
        parent::__construct('my_widget', 'My Widget', $widget_ops);
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content of the widget
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @param array $instance
     */
    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        echo $instance['title'];
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the options form on admin
     *
     * @param array $instance The widget options
     */
    public function form($instance) {

        $title = !empty($instance['title']) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__('New title', 'text_domain');
        if(isset($instance['error'])){
            echo $instance['error'];
        }
        ?>
            <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e('Title:', 'text_domain'); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('title')); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>">
            </p>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Processing widget options on save
     *
     * @param array $new_instance The new options
     * @param array $old_instance The previous options
     */
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {

        // !!!!!!!
        if (empty($new_instance['title'])) {
            $instance['error'] = "ERROR!! title empty";
        }else{
            $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        }
        return $instance;
    }

}
```

you can also check for the `error` value in the `widget function` to say that the data is not valid and the widget data needs to be updated.